# Does it exist a translation of "supercazzola" in French

Tags: traduction, expressions

This is a quite popular term in Italian. I am aware it is related to some specific Italian cultural element, so it is rather likely that a straightforward translation doesn't exist.

> Supercazzola is a nonsense, a phrase without any meaning, which
>   contains invented words, which is used as a joke, in order to mock or
>   confuse the person to whom the phrase is addressed.

Freely translated from [wikipedia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercazzola).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wikipedia page you refer has a Spanish translation which is similar to the French word [galimatias](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/galimatias), so I guess it's the closest translation. I don't hear it very often, though.

Apparently [embrouillamini](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/embrouillamini) is considered as a synonym but may not be that suitable for abstract concepts.

I would rather recommend the more frequent [charabia](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/charabia), or maybe [sabir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sabir) (although it may be offensive to certain populations, I don't know).

I don't think any of these carry the idea of being intentionally deceptive, though.

Comment: The [English translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobbledygook) given by wikipedia is *gobbledegook*, which is also usually translated into French by *charabia*.

Comment: @laure That would be *gibberish*.

Comment: Wikipedia English transaltion is somewhat imprecise, in my opinion "gobbledegook" and "supercazzola" are not the same. They have in common beeing hard to understand, but not much more.

Comment: (+1) for *charabia* that is mostly used.

Comment: +1 for charabia which is the most common in these times.  But it lacks the intentionality of the Italian word though.